# Thinking Sphinx indexing authorisation

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Fresh installation on Ubuntu. ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install sphinx search
```

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:configure`runs properly, but when
`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:index` is invoked, all indices are returning

```
indexing index 'whatever_core'...
ERROR: index 'whatever_core': sql_connect: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
 (DSN=pgsql://main:***@localhost:5432/same_development).
```

Thinking_sphinx.yml is configured as:

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/bin
  pid_file: /home/main/same/shared/tmp/searchd.pid
  configuration_file: /home/main/same/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf
  indices_location: /home/main/same/shared/sphinx
  use_64_bit: true
#  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 2
#  max_matches: 1000
  mysql41: 9313
  mem_limit: 128M
  utf8: true
```

this authentication has never been an issue previously... not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 0):

verify `database.yml`that it has proper `username` and `password` configuration.